# setdiff removes element without reason in a list?

Tags: r, list, set-difference

Given:

```
doc1 <- "Hearty Chicken Chorizo, Kale, Bean and Farro Soup"

doc2 <- "Spinach, Ham and Egg Whites Frittata – 2 Points"

doc3 <- "Lentil Tabouli"

doc4 <- "Individual Brussels Sprout & Potato Frittatas"

doc5 <- "Ahi Tuna Stacks with Ginger-Soy Dressing"

doc6 <- "Sagebrush Annie's Ventura County Cabernet Sauvignon & Merlot Ventura County"

doc7 <- "Lentil Chili"

doc8 <- "Slow Cooker Lentil Stew with Sausage"

doc9 <- "Spicy Lentil and Swiss Chard Soup"

doc10 <- "Tofu-Spinach Lasagne"

doc11 <- "Baked Ziti with Spinach"

doc12 <- "Mushroom, Spinach and Cheddar Wraps"

doc13 <- "Jamaican Jerk Pork Roast – Low Carb & Whole 30"

doc14 <- "Tofu & Broccoli Quinoa Stir-Fry"

doc15 <- "Chicken Fajita Stuffed Peppers"

doc16 <- "SketchBook Pinot Noir Wine"

doc17 <- "Chicken and Vegetable Soup"

doc18 <- "Manhattan Crab Chowder"

doc19 <- "Waterbrook Reserve Chardonnay"

doc20 <- "Chinese Beef and Broccoli"

doc21 <- "Easy Crab Curry"

doc22 <- "Waterbrook Reserve Chardonnay"

# Search for all variables starting with doc and search by name of the objects, returning named list:

doc_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^doc"))
```

And:

```
query <- "Skinny Chicken Rolls"
```

I want to exclude the query from the list L:

`setdiff(L, query)` but for some reason it returns me `21` elements given that `query` doesn't exists in `L`.

Please advise what I am missing here.

And for some reason if you will try dput(doc_list) you will get only half of the elements. What is going on here?

Comment: There is no list `L`...do you mean `doc_list`?

Comment: @Sotos, post as answer/explain which arguments are vectorized and which not?

Comment: @SteveS - dput(doc_list) isn't removing any elements.  Go ahead and use that output to create a new object. You'll see it still has 22 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicated elements in your input.  `setdiff` returns the unique elements (since it's looking at sets).  So 'query' didn't remove anything - you're just getting the output that should match `unique(L)` since "Waterbrook Reserve Chardonnay" is in your list twice.

Comment: oh, so no need for applying it?

Comment: Correct - there is no need for apply since `setdiff` will work just fine on a list.  If you use their original input you can test it out: `setdiff(doc_list, c("Lentil Chili", "Easy Crab Curry"))`

Comment: With the caveat that if your list actually contained vectors of length greater than 1 it does get more complicated.  In that case you might need to take the lapply route.  Or have a harder think about what you're trying to achieve.